# How to create multiple types of users using OneToOne field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-custom-user

I want to create 2 types of users - Customer and Company. I've already created a custom user shown below. These are their model files -

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        CUSTOMER = "CUSTOMER", "Customer"
        COMPANY = "COMPANY", "Customer"

    type = models.CharField(_("Type"), max_length=50, choices=Types.choices, default=Types.CUSTOMER)

    use_in_migrations = True
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', is_staff)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', is_superuser)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""
    username=None
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'id'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']
    objects = UserManager() 

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address')

class Company(models.Model):
    """User model."""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
```

I'm stuck at creating the serializer file. Most of the other answers use forms for creating multiple types of users, but I just want to create an API. Can anyone help me to create the serializer file for this?

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields="__all__"

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields="__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ????
```

Comment: you can add an extra field(type) in user model or serializers.

Comment: Ok! I added type in user model, but can u help me in the create method in serializer file

Comment: make user serializers . then override perform_create in views.py . save user and then create type of user  based on type.